How can i connect google cloudspanner with pyspark and also with databricks using jdbc?
I have spark version 3.5.0 and scala of 2.12 and i am using 'spark-3.1-spanner-1.0.0.jar'
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
.config("spark.jars","/home/arvind/Downloads/spark-3.1-spanner-1.0.0.jar")\
.appName("cloud spanner Testing").getOrCreate()
print(spark)
credentialFilePath = "/home/arvind/Downloads/jsonKeysFiles/citric-sol-436208-r8-099f62042467.json"
spark.conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", credentialFilePath)

# credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentialFilePath)
# print(credentials)
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = credentialFilePath



try:
   df = spark.read.format('cloud-spanner') \
      .option("projectId", "citric-sol-436208-r8") \
      .option("instanceId", "cloudspanner2") \
      .option("databaseId", "testcloudspanner") \
      .option("table", "moonatable1") \
      .load()
   df.show()


except Exception as error:
   print("Error ==",error)

I am doing this to connect but then also i am getting error as
An error occurred while calling o39.load.
: com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid credentials path specified: There are no credentials set in the connection string, and the default application credentials are not set or are pointing to an invalid or non-existing file.
Please check the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable and/or the credentials that have been set using the Google Cloud SDK gcloud auth application-default login command
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerExceptionPreformatted(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:291)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerExceptionPreformatted(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:297)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.CredentialsService.createCredentials(CredentialsService.java:71)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionOptions.(ConnectionOptions.java:748)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionOptions.(ConnectionOptions.java:85)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionOptions$Builder.build(ConnectionOptions.java:617)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.SpannerUtils.connectionFromProperties(SpannerUtils.java:180)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.SpannerTable.(SpannerTable.java:62)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.Spark31SpannerTableProvider.inferSchema(Spark31SpannerTableProvider.java:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.loadV2Source(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:208)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:127)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:129)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:101)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.CredentialsService.internalGetApplicationDefault(CredentialsService.java:98)
at com.google.cloud.spark.spanner.repackaged.com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.CredentialsService.createCredentials(CredentialsService.java:55)
... 24 more
i think there is a problem with driver is driver i am using is correct or other driver should i use..

The error indicates that the JDBC driver cannot find any credentials for Google Cloud. You are setting os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = credentialFilePath, but that is for your Python runtime environment.
I think that the problem is that this environment variable is not applied to your Spark runtime. To do that, you should set spark.executorEnv.["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = credentialFilePath.
See also https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment for more information.
